# Looping through collections -Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

**I was trying to loop through a collection based on the key**[image]

What I am trying to accomplish here is to group each company based on the alphabet in my view.

How do I loop through this??

```
$results = $companies->sortBy('name')->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
                 return substr($item['name'], 0, 1);
        });

       dump($results);
```

Controller

Comment: Is your question related to grouping or to iterate over a collection?

Comment: Did one of the below answers solve your issue? If so, please may you mark it as accepted :) Otherwise, please can you explain the issues you're still having.

Answer (score 16):

As an alternative to @msonowal's answer you can also use [each()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-each):

```
$results->each(function ($collection, $alphabet) {
    dump($alphabet, $collection);
});
```

However, if you're going to loop through them in a blade file you would use:

```
@foreach ($results as $alphabet => $collection)
    {!! dump($alphabet, $collection) !!}
@endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#loops

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($results as $alphabet => $collection) {
  dump($alphabet, $collection);
}
```