# Laravel: How can results retrieved from the database be looped through?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, loops

Laravel: How can results retrieved from the database be looped through?

If a DB facade is being used, and the mysql query results are retrieved using the following, how can the results be looped through?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$results = DB::table('misctable')->where('miscfield', $miscvariable);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through collections -Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126573/looping-through-collections-laravel)

Comment: Did you find the answer useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
foreach($results as $row){
    // do something with $row->miscfield;
}
```

to loop through your records one by one.

You might have to chain `->get()` like so `$results = DB::table('misctable')->where('miscfield', $miscvariable)->get();`

See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries docs.

Comment: The note on `->get()` is actually really important. `DB:table()->where()`, without a closure, will be an instance of the `Builder` class, which is not iterable, while appending `->get()` converts it to a `Collection`, which is.

Comment: @TimLewis True. Thanks for the good commentary. Much appreciated.