# PHP Laravel : How to Access Protected value on array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, lumen

I have problem to get value of protected array in my laravel project and want to save my data into database using foreach. I used to `print_r` my data

```
print_r($request->data);
```

Here is my array data:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 900
                    [zone_id] => 1
                    [account_id] => 2
                    [size] => 23474836488
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 9001
                    [zone_id] => 2
                    [account_id] => 2
                    [size] => 23474836488
                )
        )
)
```

Is there any solution of my problem?

Comment: Convert it to array first `print_r($request->data->toArray())`.

Comment: Would you be better off just looping over the collection - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126573/looping-through-collections-laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an array in the object.

You can access it as below.

```
foreach($request->data as $data){
    echo $data->id;
    echo $data->zone_id;
    echo $data->account_id;
    echo $data->size;
}
```

In Laravel, whenever you'll execute DB query or fetch records from database it will return you this kind of object.

If you want to see the object to array the as per @Ammar Faizi Comment you can convert it into array. `$request->data->toArray();`

Comment: Please do explain that [Collection](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) supports any array operator due to the fact that it implements `ArrayAccess` and `Enumerable`. This doesn't happen by magic.

Comment: I am getting Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::toArray() @Dilip